# Hard coded encryption without need for a key

Tags: encryption

sorry if there is an answer to this somewhere, but I could not find a clear explanation.

If I need to encrypt a sensitive field before storing it in my db, can the following approach possibly work?

I write a hard-coded encryption-cipher algorithm (in my php file) without any random behavior, like shuffling a deck of cards in a certain sequence, but only I know the exact sequence. I then also write the exact opposite algorithm to de-crypt the ciphered field, thus (hopefully) eliminating the need for a decryption key.

My understanding is that only the resulting string will be exposed to http(s) traffic and even if the result is posted back it is over https.

Can this approach work?

Comment: You cannot perform encryption / decryption without a key. Furthermore, deterministic encryption algorithms always expose identical plaintext messages, which leaks information. If the code can ever be viewed by an adversary you might need *white-box encryption*. However, if you assume that the key / algorithm remains secret and that the  messages change (e.g. using a message counter) you could have a look at e.g. AES-SIV or AES-GCM-SIV (SIV means a "synthetic IV"). Posted this as a comment since this is off topic here, it doesn't contain any programming.

Comment: Do these answers help you? https://security.stackexchange.com/q/226700/134095